# pushViewController not working for instantiated ViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Again I have encountered another problem...

I have a view which lists "covers" for each "book" like iBooks. Each of the book must be downloaded before viewing its contents. Once the contents for a book was downloaded, the user can view that contents (just a series of images).

However, suddenly my view for the book pages stop working. In my "book shelf" view which lists the covers of the books, if the book the user created was already downloaded, I instantiate another view controller for the book's page:

```
BookPageController *bookPageVc = [[BookPageController alloc] init];
bookPageVc.bookPageData = bookPageData;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bookPageVc animated:YES];
```

I already checked if it properly instantiated by NSLog, and both BookPageController and self.navigationController are existed. Yet its always crushes with the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

I didn't change/add anything for this BookPageController, it's just UIViewController.
Because when I try to another UIViewController, it works fine.

Am I missing something in BookPageController?  Any help or point to direction would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe i'm not seeing something, but the error ocurred when you insert and abject (creating the list?), but i dont see an insert action in your code.

Can you post that part?
(Or check if it is instantiated in that moment).

Comment: I can't believe that I completely forgot to change the name for the data (image) folder which the source for bookPageData. Thank you for quick answer and the point you mentioned led me to the right direction, and solved the problem!